# Expresso Store SSL Error with Authorize.net

Tags: expresso-store, ssl, authorize.net

I have had an ExpressionEngine site with Store running well for a while now, then out of the blue customers started getting errors when trying to complete checkout and pay.

I looked into it and found the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain [url] https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll' in /home/content/93/10773693/html/engine/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/guzzle/http/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php:338 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/93/10773693/html/engine/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/guzzle/http/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(279): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->isCurlException(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array) #1 /home/content/93/10773693/html/engine/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/guzzle/http/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(244): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processResponse(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array) #2 /home/content/93/10773693/html/engine/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/guzzle/http/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(22 in /home/content/93/10773693/html/engine/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/guzzle/http/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php on line 338
```

EE version 2.11.3 with Store version 2.5.1. And I am using Authorize.net as the payment gateway.

I contacted Authorize.net and they said it may be due to a recent change they made and said "the website might not be automatically validating our current SSL certificate. Here is a link that will help you, or your developer make sure your using the most up to date certifications. https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/News-and-Announcements/SSL-Certificate-Updates-for-Legacy-SDKs/m-p/62935".

How can I fix this and get Store working again? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with the same error. So annoying. Just make sure your `vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Resources/cacert.pem` certificates are updated to use the one in the Auth.net PHP SDK:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/master/lib/ssl/cert.pem

Sometimes there's more than one depending on how the dev set up composer dependencies. Just grep for any `vendor/guzzle` folders throughout or ask the plugin dev to update the packages.